# React.Component not a ReactType

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm building a React app in Typescript, and I'm getting the following error for each component I'm trying to include in my router.

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/scripts/components/AppRouter.tsx:14:25
    TS2322: Type 'typeof "E:/Programming Projects/free-food-app/src/scripts/components/OverviewPage"' is not assignable to type 'ReactType'.
  Type 'typeof "E:/Programming Projects/free-food-app/src/scripts/components/OverviewPage"' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<any>'.
    Type 'typeof "E:/Programming Projects/free-food-app/src/scripts/components/OverviewPage"' provides no match for the signature '(props: any, context?: any): ReactElement<any>'
```

I don't understand this at all. It seems like a class that extends React.Component should be able to be included in the router. Why am I getting these errors?

AppRouter.tsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import * as OverviewPage from './OverviewPage';
import * as AssignmentViewPage from './AssignmentViewPage';
import * as SubmissionEditPage from './SubmissionEditPage';
import * as SubmissionSubmitPage from './SubmissionSubmitPage';
import * as SubmissionViewPage from './SubmissionViewPage';

export default class AppRouter extends React.Component<any, any> {

  public render() {
    return (
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={OverviewPage}/>
        <Route path="/assingment" component={AssignmentViewPage}/>
        <Route path="/submission/edit" component={SubmissionEditPage}/>
        <Route path="/submission/submit" component={SubmissionSubmitPage}/>
        <Route path="/submission/" component={SubmissionViewPage}/>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: OverviewPage.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

class OverviewPage extends React.Component<any, any> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Overview</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export { OverviewPage }
```

Comment: What are the types for props and state of each component that you are passing to the router?

Comment: Can you post one of your component (OverviewPage) ? Your imports seem strange, why you import all as * ?

Comment: @soywod I started importing as `import OverviewPage from './OverviewPage';`. It changed the error message to: `TS2322: Type '{ OverviewPage: typeof OverviewPage; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactType'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'OverviewPage' does not exist in type 'ReactType'.`

Comment: @promisified I edited the question to add a component I am passing to the router.

Comment: To answer the import question. Being that you didn't use export default, your import should use the bracket syntax. Import {component}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this exact issue and what I found was this. React router is only satisfied when props and state either have a type or are an empty object. They cannot be set to any.

After paying closer attention to your edits I think the problem may be more than the type of state and props.

Since you are not using export default, you're actually exporting a key and a value where the value is your component. React router is expecting a component but you are only passing the key. You can either use default to solve your issue or use the `import {component}` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. The problem was with how I was doing exports. I think I was importing some sort of object by doing `import * as OverviewPage from './OverviewPage';`.

Instead I should `export default class OverviewPage` and import the class as `import OverviewPage from './OverviewPage';`. Once I did that it started working without complaint.